# Proving 2 lines are parallel.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, tangent-line

The point $P$ is situated outside of the circle $Ω$. Two lines, passing through $P$, are tangent to $Ω$ in $A$ and $B$. The median $AM$ of the $\triangle PAB$, with $M$ situated on $BP$, intersects the circle $Ω$ at the point $C$. The line $PC$ intersects again the circle $Ω$ at the point $D$. Prove that the lines $AD$ and $BP$ are parallel.

Comment: Can you show us your effort? Otherwise will be your question very probably closed.

Comment: What is written above...and also add a diagram of that problem, as usual in geometry, otherwise it could be not many will even bother...

Answer (score 1):

- Since $MP^2 = MB^2 = MC \cdot MA$ we conclude $BP$ is tangent to circle $(ACP)$.
- From tangent-chord property we have (use it twice): $$\angle MPC = \angle CAP = \angle ADC$$ and so $AD||BP$.

[image]

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: Thanks @SarGe Any way, what do you think about my answer?

Comment: OP recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770427/proving-that-two-segments-have-same-length) without any work or attempt. I gave a hint and flagged the question for closure. As you seem to be a new member and didn't know much about the site policy, I've neither upvoted nor did downvote your answer. :-)