# Proving that two segments have same length.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

Let $AL$ and $BK$ be angle bisectors in the non-isosceles triangle $ABC$, with $L$ situated on the side $BC$ and $K$ situated on the side $AC$. The perpendicular bisector of
$BK$ intersects the line $AL$ at point $M$. Point $N$ lies on the line $BK$ such that $LN || MK$.
Prove that $LN = NA$.

Comment: Include your attempt in the question.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Mathematics community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**Hint:** Use the property: "the intersection point of the
angle bisector of an angle of a triangle and the perpendicular bisector of the opposite side belongs to the circumcircle of the given triangle". Hence, quadrilateral $ABMK$ is cyclic.

Comment: I like your answer +1